# Javascript to replace element by id using for loop

Tags: javascript, html

Am using markdown converter javascript to convert text in user reply area, but it only get the last text from another users and place it at the top i don't know what i did wrong.

```js
<script>
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("RepIcer");
var converter1 = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
var CODESOFTLAB = new Markdown.Converter(converter1);

for( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ ){
  var input = inputs[i];
  var value = input.value;
  var MarkDownPreviewHtml = CODESOFTLAB.makeHtml(value);
  var targetId = input.id.replace("before", "replysjl");
  var targetSpan = document.getElementById( targetId );
  targetSpan.innerHTML = MarkDownPreviewHtml;
  var a = 10;
}//for()

</script>
```

```html
    <p id="reply-0"></p>
    <textarea id="replybefore-0" style="display:none;" class="RepIcer">Hello how are you</textarea>
    
    <p id="reply-5"></p>
    <textarea id="replybefore-5" style="display:none;" class="RepIcer">HHHH okay</textarea>
    
    <p id="reply-6"></p>
    <textarea id="replybefore-6" style="display:none;" class="RepIcer">Whuyyyy</textarea>
    
    <p id="reply-10"></p>
    <textarea id="replybefore-10" style="display:none;" class="RepIcer">Not working</textarea>
```

Example of my html

```
<p id="reply-0"></p>
<textarea id="replybefore-0" style="display:none;" class="RepIcer">Hello how are you</textarea>

<p id="reply-5"></p>
<textarea id="replybefore-5" style="display:none;" class="RepIcer">HHHH okay</textarea>

<p id="reply-6"></p>
<textarea id="replybefore-6" style="display:none;" class="RepIcer">Whuyyyy</textarea>

<p id="reply-10"></p>
<textarea id="replybefore-10" style="display:none;" class="RepIcer">Not working</textarea>
```

Why i have mix up the `p` and `textarea` element id is based on time the reply is inserted in the database the id of reply message from db is what i use in `reply-XX and replybefore-XX` if this is another way i can do it to add fake id like '`12345...' till last reply i will like it

Than here is my javascript to get text inside textarea and display in in p element according to the id of each element

```js
 <script>
    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("RepIcer");
        var converter1 = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
        var CODESOFTLAB = new Markdown.Converter(converter1);
        
        for( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ ){
          var input = inputs[i];
          var value = input.value;
          var MarkDownPreviewHtml = CODESOFTLAB.makeHtml(value);
          var targetId = input.id.replace("before", "replyList");
          var targetSpan = document.getElementById( targetId );
          targetSpan.innerHTML = MarkDownPreviewHtml;
          var a = 10;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Could you please turn your code paste into a snippet?

Comment: @tmslnz i didn't get what you mean sorry

Comment: Edit your question and you will see a button like `<>` in the editor. Click it and put your code in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vshs3d30/) version without Markdown, but you could elaborate from there.

Your targetId replace was not replacing properly, see below for code that works:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("RepIcer");

for( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ ){
  var input = inputs[i];
  var value = input.value;
  var targetId = input.id.replace("before", "");
  var targetSpan = document.getElementById( targetId );
  targetSpan.innerHTML = value;

}
```